# How to trigger the incognito keyboard in Android using jet pack compose without relying on the XML files?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, incognito-mode

Most android keyboards have a flag for incognito. Not all keyboards respect it.
In the case of GBoard, you can use the flag "flagNoPersonalizedLearning" from the IME Options section when creating an EditText inside a View with xml.
But what about compose? Sure Compose TexField has the `keyboardOptions` argument but i found no documentation about using it for incognito mode.
Also, when passing "flagNoPersonalizedLearning" into imeOptions like so

```
OutlinedTextField(
...
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeOptions = ImeOptions("flagNoPersonalizedLearning")),
...
)
```

Doesn't trigger it either
So how do we trigger incognito mode in a Jetpack Compose with no views?

I tried the above mentioned approach and i expected to trigger the incognito mode in gboard. Unfortunately, it didn't work as expected.